# What should I write in php if I would like to use "post" in Android programming?

Tags: php, android, http-post

What should I write in php if I would like to use "post" in Android programming? 
For example, if I want to upload my name and age form my android phone to the server,
what should I write in the server's php?
There are many examples about the use "post" of android on the internet, but less about how to write the php.

Comment: I disagree there's a wealth of resources expalining how to handle POST requests with PHP available online.  For example, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Comment: Thank you. Is it use the same format when operate with android program?

Comment: Not even close. There's lots of examples of how to send POSt data from android though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but if your referring to handling the POST headers in a HTTP request then use the Reserved variable `$_POST` in php.

e.g.

```
<?php

printf( "Hello, my name is %s and I am %d.\n", $_POST['name'], $_POST['age'] );

?>
```